# jquery click not working when coming back to page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple script that adds a click event listener to an element that is not currently on the screen. It works fine when I first visit a page but if I click a link to another page then come back it doesn't work, I don't get any errors in the console it just does nothing. Here is the script

```
$(function () {
    // event listener for removing overlay and form when clicking form close button
    addCloseButtonBehaviour();
});

function addCloseButtonBehaviour() {
    $('body').on('click', '#close-button', function () {
        $('#form-container').remove();
        $('#full-screen-overlay').remove();
    });
}
```

Can anyone tell me a way that I can do this and ensure that it works every time I visit the page? Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Using back button?

Comment: can you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: When did it stop working? After coming to the same page using back button?

Comment: If you are using the back button, jQuery's dom ready event may not fire if the page was loaded back in from cache.

Comment: it stops working if i hit the back button but it also stops working if i click a link and then the click a link that leads back to the first page

Comment: is there a ay i can make the event work even if it is loaded from the cache?

Comment: Just to be sure that the ready event fire again when you are back, add an alert('test') before calling the addCloseButtonBehaviour() function.

Comment: @antonyCas No... That doesn't work... :(

Comment: @B.Assem The alert won't trigger. :( I have had this issue... So this doesn't work. but yea, good thought.

Comment: http://www.stephenbalaban.com/back-button-doesnt-revert-reload-retrigger-scripts-jquery-javascript/

Comment: @PraveenKumar your are probably right, but what concerns me is that he said that nothing happen when he go back by clicking a back link!

Comment: @antonyCas Check the dupe to understand what's happening and know the solution to solve it too... :)

Comment: @B.Assem Check the dupe to understand what's happening and know the solution to solve it too... :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar seems cool that solution, but must be tested ;)

Comment: @B.Assem You test and lemme know, it works for me. `:D`

Comment: @PraveenKumar if it worked for you then it will work for me :D thks :D

Comment: @B.Assem Depends on browsers too mate. I am on Chrome Latest on Mac El Capitan...